# Python - Store function definition for later use

Tags: eval, pickle, python-3.5

I have an app running with many visualisations which are using bokeh. I have defined a function for each visualisation.

For new visualisations, is there a way that -

- I write the visusalisation function somewhere else e.g. jupyter notebook
- Store this function somehow in database or files, like we can do in javascript
- Use eval() to run this function later

Can you please point me a direction? I tried lambda functions but that's single line while my functions can be more complex.

In case you need something, please put in comments :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to add this function to your own class and call it for later use?

Comment: I do not need to add it to a class. Just need to call it somehow using eval() or something.

Comment: you can save your function as a python script (function.py) and when you want to call in your notebook use command "!python function.py"

Comment: I would be creating fn in notebook, save it somewhere, at runtime in the application I will load the function and call. not in notebook this time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer. Python Pickles - https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

**No Need to use eval().**

A very basic and simple example of it.

```
import pickle

def calculations(a, b):
    c = a + b
    print('Addition is ', c)
    return c

fun_def_str = pickle.dumps(calculations)

cal = pickle.loads(fun_def_str)

result = cal(5,6) # Prints - Addition is 11

print(result) # Outputs: 11
```

I hope this helps someone :)